# How to troubleshoot a wireless printer

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, network-printer

I have windows XP and I am trying to setup my new Epson NX420 wireless printer. I already have a wireless router set up and I am able to connect to the network from the printer after entering in the network name and wireless password but my computer doesn't see the printer.  When i try to run Epsonnet setup it says "Can't find printer".

The WiFi light on the printer shows greens. Would anyone know why I would be able to have my printer see the network but not be able to see the printer from my computer?

Comment: I will move this to the answers if it helps you: Make sure you have the firewall off when setting up your printer. Also, just last week, I had an HP that the software install could not find: The problem was we had software for the wrong printer, so double check that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I will move this to the answers if it helps you:
> Make sure you have the firewall off when setting up your printer.
> Also, just last week, I had an HP that the software install
> could not find:
> The problem was we had software for the wrong printer,
> so double check that too. – [KCotreau](https://superuser.com/questions/317412/how-to-troubleshoot-a-wireless-printer/1613465#comment340366_317412)